# Toggle on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I am new to web development. And I am stuck with one issue. I have implemented a flip functionality. Where if I click on the div, the element flips.  Below is what I have tried.

```
<div class = "flip" id = "flip">
  <div class = "front">
      <div id = "chartAnchor1" class="x_content">
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "back">
      <div id = "abcanchor1" class="x_content">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here `abcanchor1` and `chartanchor` are the anchor where the actual template is embedded. I am using https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ plug in to implement flip.
At present I am able to flip when the div is clicked. But I want that to happen on button click.

Code to flip :

```
$("#flip").flip();
```

But all it does is, it flips the element when clicked upon. So, default trigger is 'click' event.

I want the same functionality to work by cliking on a button rather than clicking on the div itself.

`<button type="button" id = "toggle" class = "toggle">Click Me!</button>`

Everything (flip) is working fine. All I want is to trigger the flip on a button click. It's given in this link: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ on how to implement the flip (toggle) on  button click but I am not able to implement that. Can someone guide me.

**EDIT**

```
<script>
$(function()
{
      $("#flip").flip({
  trigger: 'manual'
});
      $('#toggle').click(function() {
   $("#flip").flip('toggle');
});
 });
</script>
```

**Error: When the button is clicked I get this error**

```
 firstDashboard.html:34 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flip is not a function
```

**EDIT 2:**

Code Base:

```
<button type="button" id = "toggle" class = "toggle">Click Me!</button>

    <div class = "flip" id = "flip">
      <div class = "front">
          <div id = "chartAnchor1" class="x_content">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "back">                        
          <div id = "abcanchor1" class="x_content">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery.flip.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
     $("#flip").flip({
  trigger: 'manual'
});
   $('#toggle').click(function() {
   $("#flip").flip('toggle');
}); });
</script>
```

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flip is not a function**

[image: Error screeshot]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hv83LLbw/

You need to set trigger to `manual`:

```
$("#flip").flip({
  trigger: 'manual'
});
```

and then attached the click event handling:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
   $("#flip").flip('toggle');
});
```

The over all

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").flip({
  trigger: 'manual'
  });
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $("#flip").flip('toggle');
  });
});
```

Comment: I am new to all this. So shall I write both the function together in a single `<script> </script> tag`

Comment: I am still learning all of these. Anyways thanks for your answer. I am still getting some error may be because of silly mistake. Can you kindly see the **EDIT** portion of question.

Comment: did you include the flip library ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117830/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-joey-etamity).

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal: thanks Shubham. I don't know I get error when I call flip ('toggle'). It sas flip is not a function. Can you kindly see the error I am getting. I have attached the screenshot. I am lost!

Comment: did you include Jquery? @Unbreakable

Comment: yes. I have. jquery.min.js is included. Also, if I simply use `$("#flip").flip();`. Everything works fine. As soon as I click on the main div element. I can see the flip working.

Comment: lets use chat, how to open a chat??

Comment: It's only when I am passing `('toggle')`. I see red squiggly around the flip function.

Comment: @JoeyEtamity: You are champion. I resolved the jQuery double load issue. And it resolved the flip issue also. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hooking a click event to that button and calling `flip()` within the event handler, like this:

```
<div class="flip" id="flip">
  <div class="front">
      <div id="chartAnchor1" class="x_content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class = "back">
      <div id="abcanchor1" class="x_content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="toggle" class="toggle">Click Me!</button>
```

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#flip').flip();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you kindly see the Edit 2. I am getting some error.